# Why is $\arcsin(x) = \pi$ an impossible equation?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

Why is $\arcsin(x) = \pi$ an impossible equation, if $\sin(\arcsin(x)) = \sin(\pi)$ for $x = \sin(\pi)$?

Comment: $\arcsin$ takes values between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$.

Comment: Since $\sin$ is not injective, the "inverse" function must have a limited domain in order to maintain properties of being a function.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: However, $\arcsin(\sin\pi)\ne\pi$.

Comment: Since $\sin$ is not injective we have to restrict the domain to define an unique inverse. The domain we choose for $\sin$ to define the $\arcsin$ function is an arbitrary convention, but the most common (natural) convention is $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: In general, $$\arcsin(\sin(x))\ne x.$$

Answer (score 2):

This would imply $x=\sin\pi=0$, giving the contradiction $\arcsin x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $\sin$ maps each $I_k = [k\pi - \frac{\pi}{2},k\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}]  $, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, bijectively onto $J  = [-1,1]$. Therefore each of the functions $\sin_k = \sin \mid_{I_k} : I_k \to J$ has an inverse $\arcsin_k : J \to I_k$.

The functions $\arcsin_k$ are the branches of the arcsine and for $k=0$ we obtain the *principal value* which is simply denoted by

$$\arcsin : [-1,1] \to [- \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}] .$$

This is a universally accepted convention. We have
$$\sin(\arcsin(y)) = y \text{ for all } y \in [-1,1] ,$$
$$\arcsin(\sin(x)) = x \text{ iff } x \in [- \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]
 .$$
Note that the equation $\arcsin_k(y) = \pi$ has a solution for $k=1$ ($y = 0$) and no solution for $k \ne 1$.